# Usage of C# attribute methods

Tags: c#, attributes

In C#, what is the purpose of methods declared in attributes and how are they used?

As an example, have a look at the attribute [`MaxLengthAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2): it has a bunch of methods. One of them is the [`IsValid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute.isvalid?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_MaxLengthAttribute_IsValid_System_Object_) method, which is used to validate the property the attribute is applied to. How is this validation performed? I suppose the [`IsValid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute.isvalid?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_MaxLengthAttribute_IsValid_System_Object_) method is called against the property, but I don't find documentation on how to call attribute methods.

Note: I have a Java background. In Java, annotations are intended as metadata and are declared as `@inteface`s, thus they don't have methods.

Comment: This question is quite broad and every attribite behaves differentely. Basically an attribute does nothing in itself, it has to be analysed by some kind of framework. What this framework actually does is completely up to the attributes creator. So the framework may just check if an attribute is present, however it can of course also call its members.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: @HimBromBeere I understand that (actually attributes are very similar to Java annotations). What I don't understand is how an attribute method is called...

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde This question is actually meant to be generic. All the documentation I've found on attributes does mention how to use them and how to access their members, however there's no mention on their methods. Attributes methods are something that is missing in Java.

Comment: you need to add example in question, putting link is not good idea. this question is of no use in future if the linked page changes. so please put some examples in question so even if link is changed your question is still valid. Thanks!

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Don´t be too strict with links here. First it´s unlikely the Microsoft-docs change in the future and thus the link breaks. But even if it *may* break the question is clear enough and does not depend on the content within the link.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Okay. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all cases, the answer is simply: manually but by code that isn't yours. Some piece of code in some framework that you're using is intentionally checking for those attributes, and then *if they exist*: materializing them (preferably also with some kind of caching), and invoking the method.

Attributes don't do anything by themselves, but they are still types and can be materialized via the reflection APIs. If *you* want to write code to do this:

```
using System;

[SomeAttribute("boop")]
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = (SomeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
            typeof(P), typeof(SomeAttribute));

        // note the attribute doesn't know the context
        // so we need to pass that *in*; an attribute
        // doesn't know what it has been attached to
        obj?.DoSomething(typeof(P));
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct
    | AttributeTargets.Enum)]
class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public SomeAttribute(string name)
        => Name = name;
    public void DoSomething(Type type)
        => Console.WriteLine($"hey {type.Name} - {Name}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically an attribute does nothing in itself, it has to be analysed by some kind of framework. What this framework actually does is completely up to the attributes creator. So the framework may just check if an attribute is present, however it can of course also call its members.

So imagine you have this code:

```
[MyAttribute]
class MyClass
{
}

class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public void DoSomething();
}
```

Now you have some code that checks if the attribuite is present and if so calls `DoSomething`:

```
// get types with the attribute
var typesAndAttributes= myAssembly.GetTypes().Select(x => new 
    { 
        Type = x, 
        Attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(MyAttribute)) 
    });

// now call DoSomething for every attribute
forerach(var e in typesAndAttributes)
{
    e.Attribute?.DoSomething();
}
```

In your example of `MaxLengthAttribute` this means the following. If you´d decorate your member like this:

```
MaxLengthAttribute(2)
public int[] MyArr = new int[3];
```

and execute the code the framework calls `IsValid` for `MyArr` and will probably (not sure about it, didn´t inspect the sourcecode) return false, as the value contains 3 elements although only two are considered valid.

Answer (score 0):

> As an example, have a look at the attribute MaxLengthAttribute: it has a bunch of methods. One of them is the IsValid() method, which is used to validate the property the attribute is applied to. How is this validation performed? I suppose the IsValid() method is called against the property, but I don't find documentation on how to call attribute methods.

Here's a very simple example:

```
// Start off with an object we're going to validate
public class Foo
{
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Bar { get; set; } 
}

var objectToValidate = new Foo() { Bar = "123456" };

// Use reflection to get a list of properties on the object
var properties = objectToValidate.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    // For each property, get the attributes defined on that property
    // which derive from the ValidationAttribute base class
    var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes<ValidationAttribute>();

    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(objectToValidate);

    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    {
        // For each attribute, call its IsValid method, passing in the value
        // of the property
        bool isValid = attribute.IsValid(propertyValue);
        if (!isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is invalid", property.Name); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is more or less what [`Validator.ValidateObject`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/Validator.cs,336) does, except with a lot more caching.

(In the case of the DataAnnotations methods, the [TypeDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor?view=netframework-4.7.2) infrastructure is actually used. This lets you effectively add attributes to classes and their properties without modifying the source of the class directly).

[Runnable example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lgeh0J)